# Are there situations where it would be a good idea to write your own copy constructor but not your own assignment operator?

Tags: c++

The question is pretty self explanatory. If you are required to create one of them does that imply you have to create the second one too?

Comment: [Rule of three (C++ programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: @herohuyongtao That's only a rule of thumb though. Does it hold for all cases?

Comment: The reason you write a copy ctor is that the default copy ctor won't do the job. So how would the default assignment operator do the job?

Comment: @ooga I suppose so. The answer seemed relatively obvious, so I suspected I was glancing over some subtlety.

Answer (score 2):

The usual need to write these is, as mentioned in the comments above.

However, one can imagine other needs that fit your question.  For example, if you want to count the number of objects in your program.  A copy constructor will need to increment a counter, whereas an assignment does not change the number of objects, and therefore the default will do.

Answer (score 1):

When it does not make sense to assign-to an object of a certain type, you do not write/delete the assingnment op. It still might make sense to have a copy *ctor* though.

A technical example is a class with reference members. Copy construction is possible, copy assignment not really as you cannot change what the ref members point to.